# MySQL count rows with same values

Tags: mysql, count

i have been searching but i didnt find what i was looking for.
This is what i have:

```
SELECT user_email, post_type
FROM `wp_users`
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_users.id = wp_posts.post_author
WHERE post_type LIKE '%topic%'
OR post_type LIKE '%reply%
```

it bring what i needed:
I needed a query that shows me the email of an user and how many topics and replys he made (BBPRESS).

The problem is that it brings all of them but it doesnt tell me how many topics / replies the user made.
This is what it brings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMymU.png
Is there any way to add a 3rd column where it counts?

Comment: You can `group by` `user_email` and do a `count` on the `post_type` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_email, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN post_type LIKE '%reply%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Replies,
       SUM(CASE WHEN post_type LIKE '%topic%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Topics
FROM `wp_users`
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_users.id = wp_posts.post_author
WHERE post_type LIKE '%topic%' OR post_type LIKE '%reply%'
GROUP BY user_mail
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT user_email,
    SUM(CASE WHEN post_type LIKE '%topic%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Topics, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN post_type LIKE '%reply%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Replies
  FROM `wp_users`
  INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_users.id = wp_posts.post_author
  GROUP BY user_email
```